# How to fix 'Date Time Parse Exception' in Java

Tags: java, datetime-format, localdate, parseexception

I have a Date Time Formatter Which I am trying to format inputted dates into format (d/MM/yyyy) Shown Below

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

I am then using this formatter to take user input on date of birth as a String and then attempting to parse that through to store as a LocalDate variable with temp storing the user inputted date of birth

```
public void addCustomer() throws ParseException {
        customerID++;
        //Create Scanner
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Take user input
        System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter your Date of Birth(dd/MM/yyyy): ");
        String temp = scan.nextLine();
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(temp);
        Customer c = new Customer(customerID, name, date, false, "N/A");
        customers.add(c);
    }
```

However this always returns a DateTimeParseException: Text could not parse. Is the issue in how I am setting up the Date Time Formatter to always cause this exception? Shown Below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '27/01/1999' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2046)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:428)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:413)
    at BikeNow.addCustomer(BikeNow.java:153)
    at BikeNow.main(BikeNow.java:98)
```

Comment: What's your input?

Comment: What is the exact content of `temp`?

Comment: So the content of temp will always be the date of birth of the user e.g 27/01/2000

Comment: **d** /MM/yyyy? What about dates other than 1-9?

Comment: Oh yeah just noticed that typo, Updated question

Comment: This is working in my environment... Please show us the stack trace and the input that caused the `Exception`.

Comment: I am guessing there is some sort of `scan.nextInt()` or something before the lines that you have shown us. This is why we want a [mcve], rather than just a few lines of code.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I have updated the question with the full method

Comment: Your code doesn't actually use the `format` variable that you created.

Comment: `LocalDate.parse(temp, format)`

Comment: @RealSkeptic in the code before the question update, the defined `DateTimeFormatter` was used correctly. However, this is the reason (here/now), most likely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass your `DateTimeFormatter` object.

Change this:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(temp);
```

…to this:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(temp, format);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you forgot the parameter, here is the fix:

```
public void addCustomer() throws ParseException {
        customerID++;
        //Create Scanner
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Take user input
        System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter your Date of Birth(dd/MM/yyyy): ");
        String temp = scan.nextLine();

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(temp, formatter);
        Customer c = new Customer(customerID, name, date, false, "N/A");
        customers.add(c);
}
```